# How to get the opportunity owner name instead of owner ID

Tags: apex, trigger, chatter, opportunity

I am posting to chatter using an apex trigger whenever the opportunity stage changes to a certain value. The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to concatenate the opportunity owner name with some text but I can only get the ID of the owner. Is there a way I can simply get the opportunity owner name and concatenate it with the text? The query is returning the list i want but displays the key value pair, and i just want to get the firstname and lastname.

```
List<User> name= new List<User>();
name = [SELECT FirstName FROM User WHERE Id=:o.Opp_Owner_Name__c];
post.Body = 'Test' + name.get(0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select o.Owner.Name, o.Owner.FirstName, o.Owner.LastName, o.OwnerId From Opportunity o where o.Id in Trigger.NewMap.Keyset();
```

Please use the following query as Priyanka Rightly said that we cannot get those directly in Trigger.New .

Comment: Yep thanks, I did that. Only problem is it returns something like this (key, value pair) :{FirstName=Joe, Id=005Q0000001EWtDIHY}. How can I grab just the firstname and lastname as text so i can assign to post.body?

Comment: Post the code if you have that you are trying so that i can help.

Comment: List<User> name= new List<User>();
name = [SELECT FirstName FROM User WHERE Id=:o.Opp_Owner_Name__c];post.Body = 'Concatenate this' + name.get(0);

Comment: It basically returns a list, but i just want to print out the first name and last name in the list.

Comment: List<User> name= new List<User>(); name = [SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM User WHERE Id=:o.Opp_Owner_Name__c];post.Body =name.get(0).FirstName+name.get(0).Lastname;

Comment: Great! It worked, Thanks for the help man! You're awesome!

Answer (score 4):

In the trigger context, you will get only opportunity owner id in the trigger.new() map. You have to query to get the opportunity owner name.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is create a lookup to user on the opportunity. and then keep the ownerId and that lookup in sync with a workflow or trigger and then you can create formula's to that newly created lookup. then you can access all you need from that user object.